# SQL Server delete rows with trigger on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,

- `evaluer` table

  id_ch int |  id_abonne int foreign key references abonne| evaluation int |

`abonne` table

```
id int primary key | name
```

I have to add a trigger to the `evaluer` table on insert. The trigger should stop inserting if there are more than 5 records for that `idabonne` already. I can do the code that works on inserting row by row, but I want it to work for multiple rows, too, and I don't want to use a cursor. I used join but it didn't work

```
create trigger eval
on evaluer
instead of insert
as
begin
    insert into evaluer(id_ch, id_abonne, evaluation)
        select * 
        from inserted i
        join (select ev.id_abonne
              from evaluer ev
              join inserted ins on ins.id_abonne = ev.id_abonne
              group by ev.id_abonne
              having count(*) <= 5) tc on i.id_abonne = tc.id_abonne
end
```

Is there a way to do it without cursor?

Comment: So if the application inserts more than 5 rows and your <code> simply ignores everything after the fifth one, do you think it is wise to simply drop the "extras" invisibly without any feedback to the application? Or does "stop inserting" actually mean that an error should be raised that your application can then respond to in some fashion?

Comment: I have to agree with @SMor, "silent" failures from your DB server are generally a bad idea that tend to cause a lot of problems later on.  For instance, the `inserted` pseudotable has no implicit order so if you insert more than five rows, there's no guarantee which ones will actually get inserted.

Comment: i would like to show a message after stop inserting and the trigger should insert the 5 first records then stop adding more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
create trigger eval
on evaluer
instead of insert
as
begin
if (select count(*) from inserted)<6
    insert into evaluer(id_ch,id_abonne,evaluation)
    select * from inserted;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a different approach, 5 is an arbitrary number and changing a trigger when someone decides the number should change can be a hassle. I recommend creating a 3rd table called `EvaluerLimit` that is just an identity/primary key, then insert into it 5 times. then create a `NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY` in `Evaluer`, and your `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER` will manage that id. This will makes the limit data driven, when errors occur future maintainers/coders will be able to figure out the issue easier.

I'd also like to note, you mentioned deleting old records, you have a database and in the world today you shouldn't be deleting records you want to delete them not because you only want five records, if that is the case you should change your select query to top 5 (possible order by insert date desc) and not create a trigger.

below is how I'd make the limit and this is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5fd2f/1) you can see it in action

```
 CREATE TABLE EvaluerLimit(
   Id TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
 );
  
 CREATE TABLE Evaluer(
   Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   AbonneId INT NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT FK_Evaluer_Abonne_Id
     FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Abonne(Id),
   EvaluerLimitId TINYINT NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT FK_Evaluer_EvaluerLimit_Id
     FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EvaluerLimit(Id),
     CONSTRAINT UQ_Evaluer_AbonneId_EvaluerLimitId
     UNIQUE(AbonneId, EvaluerLimitId)
);
 
DECLARE @i TINYINT = 0
WHILE @i < 5 BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO EvaluerLimit DEFAULT VALUES
   SET @i = @i + 1
END;

CREATE TRIGGER TR_EvaluerInsert ON Evaluer
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @limit TINYINT 
   SELECT @limit = ISNULL(MAX(e.EvaluerLimitId),0)+1 
   FROM Evaluer e
   INNER JOIN inserted 
     ON e.AbonneId = inserted.AbonneId
   
   INSERT INTO Evaluer(AbonneId, EvaluerLimitId)
   SELECT inserted.AbonneId, @limit
   FROM inserted
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I renew the concerns that I raised in the comments above, if I had to do this, I would probably use something like this:

```
create trigger eval
on evaluer
instead of insert
as
begin
    insert into evaluer(id_ch, id_abonne, evaluation)
        select i.*
        from (select i.*, 
                row_number() over(partition by i.id_abonne order by (select null)) as iRowCount
              from inserted i) i
        join (select ev.id_abonne, count(id_abonne) as evCount
              from evaluer ev
              group by ev.id_abonne) ev  ON  ev.id_abonne = i.id_abonne
                                   And evCount < 5
                                   And iRowCount <= 5 - evCount

end
```

This adds a column to `inserted` that keeps a running count of the new rows for each `id_abonne`, and also summarized (`group by`) table from `evaluer` that has the total count of the already existing rows for each id_abonne.  Then it joins them on `id_abonne` filtering out any `inserted` rows that would put the id_abonne row counts over 5 and inserts what remains into the table.